# Geometry shader with additional clipplanes

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I wrote a geometry shader for generating thicker lines. But now i've the problem, that the attribute `[clipplanes(...)]` does not work. There is the warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning X3554   unknown attribute clipplanes, or attribute invalid for this statement, valid attributes are: maxvertexcount, MaxVertexCount, instance   CRenderer   \Shaders\GeometryShader\GS_GenerateThickLines.hlsl

I know there is the option to write the clipping of a triangle on my own, but it seem to me like a bit too mush effort. Is there a way of using additional clipplanes in geometry shaders?
I also have another idea: the geometry shader gets in a line (2 Vertices) and inside the vertex shader the `[clipplanes(...)]` attribute works... can I somehow get the clipping point instead of the original vertex inside the geometry shader? 
For more information you can find my geometry shader here: [Render thick lines with instanced rendering in directx 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510542/render-thick-lines-with-instanced-rendering-in-directx-11/43518929#43518929)

Comment: Using float cd : SV_ClipDistance as output of your GS with cd = dot(clipPlane, vertexPosition); should do the same? and does not look like to be so much effort?

Comment: @catflier thank you for your response, but with that idea I only can have one additional clipplane, or can I use this technique to add more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[clipplanes]

This attribute is only allowed on Vertex Shader, 
this has been specifically added in order to support low profile devices (here mostly read: phones).

If you need to perform culling on geometry shader, you can use SV_ClipDistance, which will limit you onto D3D#_CLIP_OR_CULL_DISTANCE_ELEMENT_COUNT.

This limit is actually of 2, so you can provide 2 variables as per :

```
struct gs2ps
{
    float4 pos: SV_Position;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float cd0 : SV_ClipDistance0;
    float cd1 : SV_ClipDistance1;
}; 

cbuffer cbClipPlanes : register(b1) 
{
   float4 clipPlane0;
   float4 clipPlane1;
};

gs2ps op;
op.cd0 = dot(clipPlane0, position);
op.cd1 = dot(clipPlane1, position);
```

Besides the 2 elements limitation, please not that it eventually offers a bit more flexibility (as you can provide your own clipping function)

In case the limit of 2 planes is a real issue for your use case, other option is to perform the plane clipping in Pixel Shader:

- Use a Zero alpha value (if depth/stencil is unimportant)
- Use clip or discard

For the second case, you will need to pass your screen space value as another semantic to your pixel shader, like:

```
struct psInput
{
    float4 pos: SV_POSITION;
    float4 screenPos : SCPOS;
};
```

(Pass the same value in pos/screenPos)

```
float4 PS(psInput input): SV_Target
{
    clip(dot(clipPlane0, input.screenPos));
    clip(dot(clipPlane1, input.screenPos));
    return color;
}
```

In that case you can have an unlimited amount of clip planes, but please note that clip is not msaa friendly.

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved my day! I'll handle you over the bounty in 19h

Comment: Note that you're not actually limited to two planes with SV_ClipDistance[n] notation. You can make cd0 and cd1 float4 vectors in the example above, giving access to the full 8 hardware clip planes.